# How can I mention router path in array object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am tying to give router path on array object, so that I can dynamically pass it to the HTML `[routerLink]`. But I am not getting how can I pass router path to the array object key value so that I can bind it.

**Router Module:-**

```
 {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: CmsComponent },
      {
        path: 'mydashboard',
        component: MyDashboardComponent,
      }
      ]
    }
```

**In Component file :-**

```
export class LeftNavComponent implements OnInit {

     navItems = [
        {
          "element": "MyDashboard",
          "url" : "../../../assets/images/icons/Travel.svg",
          "screen":"/mydashboard"                        // ---------->Here I want to pass the path.
        }   
    }
```

**HTML :-**

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let navItem of navItems">
              <a [routerLink]="navItem.screen"> // <------------Here
                <span class="sidebar-icon">
                    <img [src]="navItem.url" height="20px" width="20px" class="img">
                </span>
                <span class="sidenav-link">{{navItem.element}}</span> 
              </a>
            </li>
```

How can I achieve this ? I have more data which I am doing dynamically .

Comment: Are you getting any errors? where did you stuck exactly?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti No, I am not getting any error. I just want to know how I can pass the router path to the array object so that I can use dynamically on html routerLink. Upon clicking no route is happening.

Comment: Above code is working as expected right? are you asking for best way to do it?

Comment: must work, your DashBoardComponent has a LeftNavComponent  and a `<router-outlet><router-outlet>`, any way you should see the direcction in navigator change.

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti the code is not working . You can suggest other ways.

Comment: @Eliseo I didn't get that. Yes in dashboard html I have router outlet.

Comment: try `[routerLink]="[navItem.screen]"`, but I don't know the reason your code not work

Comment: @Eliseo did every approach not working. Isn't it because of authguard ?

Comment: if you has an error in authguard or the authguard send you a path not exist, this can be the reason, if your authguard work propertly should work